# How to make multiple queries in one promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm using React to send data over to my PotgreSQL database using NodeJS. Data is getting inserted fine on the first INSERT as well as the second INSERT but my only problem is that on the .then after the second INSERT it doesn't give me the response?

```
const addData = (request, response) => {
const uuid = uuidv4(); 

db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *' , [request.body.title, request.body.date, request.body.description, uuid])
    .then(res => {
      console.log('INSERT ' + JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]));
    }).then(() => {
       for (let i = 0; i < request.body.files.length; i++) {
        db.pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (id, name, link, index) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (album_id, index) DO NOTHING RETURNING *', [uuidv4(), request.body.files[i].name, request.body.files[i].link, request.body.files[i].index])
        }}).then(res => {
      console.log('INSERT INTO songs ' + JSON.stringify(res));
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));

}
```

What am I doing wrong to not get the response for the second INSERT?

Comment: you need to return a promise in `.then(() => {` ...

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay. What would that look like?

Comment: for a start there's the `return` statement - but it's not that simple with multiple queries in there - probably need a `.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tl;DR

This should get your code to work:

```js
const addData = (request, response) => {
  const uuid = uuidv4();
  db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *', [request.body.title, request.body.date, request.body.description, uuid])
    .then(res => {
      console.log('INSERT ' + JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]));
    }).then(() => {
      const dbQueryPromises = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < request.body.files.length; i++) {
        dbQueryPromises.push(db.pool.query(
          'INSERT INTO songs (id, name, link, index) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (album_id, index) DO NOTHING RETURNING *',
          [uuidv4(),
          request.body.files[i].name,
          request.body.files[i].link,
          request.body.files[i].index]));  
      }
      return Promise.all(dbQueryPromises);
    }).then(res => {
      console.log('Array of INSERT result for second insert: ', res);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

#### Longer explantion:

You did not get a response on the second `insert` is because you did not return any `Promise` back to the output. The first `then` works because what `db.pool.query` does is returning a `Promise.resolve(res)` of your function call. However, your second insert does not return any thing.

Take a look at this part of your code:

```js
() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < request.body.files.length; i++) {
        db.pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (id, name, link, index) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (album_id, index) DO NOTHING RETURNING *', [uuidv4(), request.body.files[i].name, request.body.files[i].link, request.body.files[i].index])
      }
    }
```

-> This is an arrow function, and in javascript if you do not return anything, if you just gave out null.

Aside from that, you are actually creating `multiple promises` at once, I would suggest for you to use `Promise.all) if you want wait for all the promise to work.

Comment: if `request.body.files` is an Array, then this code can be much simpler using array map method